# Logging in Oracle Application Express as a Database user

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

As a part of database security I have different access for every user(same as schema in Oracle). Now I want to add these users as Oracle Application Express(Apex) users. 
When I try to create new users, APEX does not provide me the ability to have database users as APEX users itself.

Essentially I have three users - STUDENT,TEACHER AND UNIVERSITY. 
UNIVERSITY has two table - STUDENT_INFO and TEACHER_INFO
STUDENT DB User is not allowed to view info of TEACHER_INFO and similarly TEACHER DB User is not allowed to view info of STUDENT_INFO.
I wanted to show this information through APEX rather than sqlplus. hence I need STUDENT User to login into the APEX and try to access UNIVERSITY.TEACHER_INFO and UNIVERSITY.STUDENT_INFO to show the difference. How can I add these users as APEX Users if I already have admin privileges to APEX.

Comment: Is this via a workspace at https://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html or have you got a local copy? Because f it's via the link, then its a demo only.

Comment: Are you trying to create users for your application or  users for access to APEX IDE? And where you want to show tables?

Comment: @simonatrcl I have the application running at localhost:8080/apex
Not sure what you are asking but I hope this answers.

Comment: @Dmitry I want to access the UNIVERSITY Schema tables through STUDENT user. Just like in SqlPlus I would do:
>connect STUDENT/password
>select * from UNIVERSITY.STUDENT_INFO;
I want to use the APEX Application to access these tables through the users. So yes, I want to create users to access APEX and those users should be the same as Database users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of,  APEX users are not database users.   Apex users are pseudo users that have schema grants by the Apex administration area.

I am assuming here that you are not trying to create an authentication scheme in Apex, totally different subject.

If you create a workspace in Apex that has access to all 3 schemas (which is no problem).  You create a single admin (again pseudo apex user) with full control.

That admin can create other users inside the adminstration->users interface. There he can grant access to all, none or subset of the schemas. Define them as application users, developers (which you want, so they can log into apex) or admins (do not want)

I took this from the internet.  Notice the accessible schemas field.,  There you define it.
[image]

Comment: This clears the confusion.I was trying to be naive and wanted to make an application where the STUDENT user logs into the app and sees different results for student and teacher tables in university schema. I guess this is not possible through APEX, will have to use SQL Developer itself.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to get access to tables in `SQL Workshop`?
First you need to know, that oracle database users and oracle APEX users are different things. After creating APEX users you need to go to `Administration` and find there menu for managing workspaces. I have no APEX now besides account at apex.oracle.com (administration functions there restricted), and don't remember exact names of menus. You need to give that users access to workspace (if necessary), and after that define, which database SCHEMAs this workspace can use (it is also in workspace management section). It can use one SCHEMA by default and other SCHEMAs can be added later. After adding SHEMAs UNIVERSITY and STUDENT you will get access to their objects in `SQL Workshop`.

Link to documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b32258/adm_wrkspc.htm#BABDEBHA